# SQLite ArrayList<Bitmap> Android

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, android-sqlite

I have a question about SQLite. I'm trying to save a custum objects (let's say ObjectA) on my phone's db. ObjectA contains an ArrayList.
I'll probably have to save the images as BLOBs but how should I design my database. Should I create a new table with all my pictures (BLOB byte[], INTEGER objectA_row_id) ? or is there another way to make this association?

Answer (score 0):

May be create table with path to the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store file path directly in database, because if you delete the file then you will not get image, so you have 2 options: 
1) Store image to your cache/internal and then save its file path.
2) Use database table containing BLOB type.